# About:blank icon

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я с помощью скриптов создал about:blank.
Я не могу поставить иконку `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">`. Что только не пробовал, но иконка не отображается. Помогите.

Comment: http://www.favicon.cc/
вот онлайн сервис - иконка должна быть в корне сайта

Comment: Он и есть в корне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about:blank, насколько я понимаю, - это броузерная заглушка. Ей мы не можем присвоить ничего.

Сделайте у себя страницу `site.ru/zaglushka.html`.

И на нее уже лепите фавикон.

Comment: Ну а как я могу редактировать со страницы, другую страницу?

Comment: Извините, но, я не понимаю Ваш вопрос.

У вас нет возможности создать новую страницу?

Если вы хотите редактировать из одного место - другое, тогда вам нужно аджаксом пользоваться, и делать все обновления в рамках одной страницы.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yh95thef/3/